# Angularjs: Using ng-class to add a class to completed progress step

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller, ng-class

I am trying to add a class to a completed step indicator on the progress bar but cannot figure out how to do it. A step is completed when a button is clicked on the page and takes the user to the next page (next step). So when this happens, I want to add a class to the previous step indicator on the progress bar that will indicate it was completed. Here is where I want it to happen: data-ng-class="{checked:isChecked($index)}". The function doesn't necessarily have to pass $index, I was just taking a stab at it. I am able to do this for the active progress step, just not a previous one. I'm racking my brain trying to figure it out but have a feeling I am overthinking it.

```
<div data-ng-controller="ProgressBarCtrl">
  <div class="progress-bar">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="step in steps" data-ng-class="{active:isActive('{[{ step.path }]}')}">
        <div class="progress-content">
          <span data-ng-class="{checked:isChecked($index)}" class="number-circle">{[{ step.step }]}</span>
          <span class="progress-copy">{[{ step.desc }]}</span>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


angular.module('progressBar', [])

.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider){
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }])

.controller("ProgressBarCtrl", ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {

  $scope.isActive = function(route) {
    // console.log('route ' + route);
    // console.log('path ' + $location.path());
    return route === $location.path();
  }

  $scope.steps = [
    { "step" : 1, "desc" : "Choose Plan", "path" : "/offers" },
    { "step" : 2, "desc" : "Customize", "path" : "/customize"},
    { "step" : 3, "desc" : "My Info", "path" : "/customer_details"},
    { "step" : 4, "desc" : "Installation"},
    { "step" : 5, "desc" : "Payment"}
  ]

  $scope.isChecked = function($index) {
    // Not sure what to do here or if this even the right approach
  }

}]);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you had it close, try `ng-class="{'checked': isChecked($index)}"`

Comment: Thanks @aarosil for the syntax correction. This doesn't solve my problem though. As you can see, there is nothing in the function that is called there. I am trying to figure out how to do this.

Comment: Can't really tell what you're trying to do, but maybe something like `span.span >= $index` would work in that function?

Comment: @aarosil I put more clarification into the description. I did try something like that but couldn't get it to work. Could you be more specific given the details and code? Let me know if it's still fuzzy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of the current step's index and compare it to the `$index` value.

```
// ...

.controller("ProgressBarCtrl", ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {

  $scope.currentIndex = 0; // default to 0

  $scope.isActive = function(route) {
    // console.log('route ' + route);
    // console.log('path ' + $location.path());
    if(route === $location.path()){
      // set current index value here
      angular.forEach($scope.steps, function(step,i){
        if(route === step.path){
          $scope.currentIndex = i;
        }
      });
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };

  $scope.steps = [
    { "step" : 1, "desc" : "Choose Plan", "path" : "/offers" },
    { "step" : 2, "desc" : "Customize", "path" : "/customize"},
    { "step" : 3, "desc" : "My Info", "path" : "/customer_details"},
    { "step" : 4, "desc" : "Installation"},
    { "step" : 5, "desc" : "Payment"}
  ];

  $scope.isChecked = function($index) {
    return $index < $scope.currentIndex;
  };

}]);
```

Haven't tested this code, but the general idea should work.